# Handle an exception with Ruby Watir

Tags: watir

```
    @b.link(:class => "DeleteVendor").click
    @b.button(:class => "btn btn-danger").click
    begin
    raise if error.message != /Server Error/
    rescue Watir::Exception::NavigationException => e
    puts "Page did not load: #{e}"
    end
end
```

When I run my script I get syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
Please help me understand if I need to define 'e' and how. Thanks!
What I am trying to do is put the exception. Sometimes when I submit a form I get a server error so I would like to handle that in my script for this case or if there is a better way to handle it globally so that if any script triggers the Server error then puts the error.

Comment: `Begin` should be `begin`.

Comment: True. I fixed the capitalization and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution as I had inadvertently added two begins in different places in my script. I hope that helps someone else when debugging. Doh!